# Office 365 Unified APIs: WorkingWith relationship

Tags: office365

I am using the recently published for preview Office 365 Unified Web APIs. In general they work, but at least one of the API endpoints is either not working, or it is not documented properly.

For instance, the following GET request returns my manager: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/manager

But, calling this URL https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/WorkingWith returns a 400 Bad Request, even though it should return the colleagues that I am most collaborating with.

Preview features and Graph queries are enabled both in Office 365 and SharePoint Online settings.

Is anyone experiencing a similar issue? O ris there someone from MS to anser?

Answer (score 1):

The functionality for /workingWith and /trendingAround is deploying in our production services worldwide and at this point in time it might be that your particular instance has not been updated yet. Please give it a week or so and you should have the functionality on your tenant.
Kind regards,
Yina

Comment: Thank you for the answer! One more question. Currently accessing /beta/me/manager, /beta/me/directReports requires admin consent (it needs the Access directory as Signed In user permission, which needs admin consent). We are developing a mobile app, so it cannot get admin consent. And in general - why? This is really a limitation. If the new /workingWith will require the same, it will be very sad - basically, these great APIs will not be available for mobile apps.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to still not be working... Is it already deployed, or is it still ongoing?

Comment: It's getting there... you can try it in the /alpha endpoint. But a word of caution: it is still a bit unstable.

Comment: IT works, but it currently requires Admin consent... This pretty much kills the idea, as Admin consent cannot be given to a mobile app. If you can, please communicate it to the azure team.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, we will be adding an additional scope that can give you access to basic user data with out requiring user consent.

Comment: Hello! I noticed that now there is the "Read users' relevant people lists (preview)". It is still returning 403 Access Denied error when I am trying with this scope... Do you have some updates about this?

Comment: Using /workingWith still requires admin consent. Or, is there some other scope that ew can use? We did not find any way to get it working so far without admin consent.

Answer (score 1):

Please review https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/graph-api-permission-scopes.  You'll see that this permission CAN be consented to by end users on mobile apps (native clients). The admin consent restriction only applies to web apps. Are you seeing a different behavior here?

In time we hope to also introduce some more granular scopes (in the underlying directory) that will allow users to consent to this information without needing to use what is essentially full user impersonation.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Actually this works exactly as documented. But this describes the old Graph api. I am refering to the new Unified Office 365 APIs. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: the scopes are the same and the same applies for which can be consented by end-users